# Python: Running maximum by another column?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, max

I have a dataframe like this, which tracks the value of certain items (ids) over time:

```
mytime=np.tile( np.arange(0,10) , 2 )
myids=np.repeat( [123,456], [10,10] )
myvalues=np.random.random_integers(20,30,10*2)

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['myids']=myids
df['mytime']=mytime
df['myvalues']=myvalues



+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| myids | mytime | myvalues |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 123   | 0      | 29       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 123   | 1      | 23       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 123   | 2      | 26       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 123   | 3      | 24       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 123   | 4      | 25       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 123   | 5      | 29       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 123   | 6      | 28       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 123   | 7      | 21       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 123   | 8      | 20       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 123   | 9      | 26       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 456   | 0      | 26       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 456   | 1      | 24       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 456   | 2      | 20       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 456   | 3      | 26       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 456   | 4      | 29       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 456   | 5      | 29       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 456   | 6      | 24       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 456   | 7      | 21       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 456   | 8      | 27       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
| 456   | 9      | 29       |  |  |
+-------+--------+----------+--+--+
```

I'd need to calculate the running maximum for each id.

```
np.maximum.accumulate()
```

would calculate the running maximum regardless of id, whereas I need a similar calculation, which however resets every time the id changes. I can think of a simple script to do it in numba (I have very large arrays and non-vectorised non-numba code would be slow), but is there an easier way to do it?

With just two values I can run:

```
df['running max']= np.hstack((  np.maximum.accumulate(df[ df['myids']==123 ]['myvalues']) , np.maximum.accumulate(df[ df['myids']==456 ]['myvalues']) )  )
```

but this is not feasible with lots and lots of values.

Comment: [pandas groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) — you can write and accept your own answer...

Comment: I group by myids, then, what exactly? I'm sure it's just me being thick, but I come from a SQL background and I really struggle to get my head around pandas (also, the atrocious documentation doesn't help)...

Comment: `df.groupby('myid')['myvalues'].cummax()` is pretty close, but I don't know how to proceed further... `.cummax()` takes an `axis=` argument but, as a pandas ignoramus. i don't know how to use it (anyway it's not exactly a numpy `axis=`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Assumption is mytime is sorted.

```
mytime=np.tile( np.arange(0,10) , 2 )
myids=np.repeat( [123,456], [10,10] )
myvalues=np.random.random_integers(20,30,10*2)

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['myids']=myids
df['mytime']=mytime
df['myvalues']=myvalues

groups = df.groupby('myids')
df['run_max_group'] = groups['myvalues'].transform(np.maximum.accumulate)
```

Output...

```
    myids  mytime  myvalues  run_max_group
0     123       0        27             27
1     123       1        21             27
2     123       2        24             27
3     123       3        25             27
4     123       4        22             27
5     123       5        20             27
6     123       6        20             27
7     123       7        30             30
8     123       8        24             30
9     123       9        22             30
10    456       0        29             29
11    456       1        23             29
12    456       2        30             30
13    456       3        28             30
14    456       4        26             30
15    456       5        25             30
16    456       6        28             30
17    456       7        27             30
18    456       8        20             30
19    456       9        24             30
```

Comment: Is transform() documented anywhere? This link: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html?highlight=transform#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform shows literally nothing. This other link : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html?highlight=transform#transformation says something but not a lot

Comment: I'm not familiar with documentation. I can try to explain it... If you know how the aggregate function works you know how transform does. It simply expands the resulting value from aggregate to match the size of the group. So lets say I have group a with values [1, 2, 3] and group b with values [3, 4, 5]. If I do groups.aggregate(max) I will get back a=3 and b=5. groups.transform will give me a=[3,3,3] and b=[5,5,5]. This makes modifying or adding to an existing DataFrame a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is indeed not too difficult

```
byid = df.groupby('myid')
rmax = byid['myvalues].cummax()
for k, indices in byid.indices.items():
    print 'myid = %s' % k
    print 'running max = %s' % rmax[indices]
```

I have (almost) no previous pandas, but using `ipython` as an exploratory instrument I was able to find a solution.  I recommend the use of `ipython` to explore large and complex libraries.

p.s. re my previous comment: no need for `axis=`